# JavaScript read Network Response instead of Error Code

Tags: javascript

When I make too many calls, Facebook returns the following network response:

```
{error: {,…}}
error: {,…}
code: 80004
error_subcode: 2446079
fbtrace_id: "A9AsI5BnLkI3SjvBHT4m_W7"
message: "(#80004) There have been too many calls to this ad-account. Wait a bit and try again. For more info, please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting."
type: "OAuthException"
```

I'm trying to show the user a friendly message, but can't quite catch the error code. I'm trying:

```
try {
 resp = await axios.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/act_'.concat(ad_account_id,'/adimages'), {params: data});
 } catch (error) {
 if (error.code==80004) { 
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "Too many calls to API. Wait a bit then retry."; 
 }
};
```

How do I catch / reference this error code?

Comment: Could you share the full `try{} catch()`-block of your code? Else it will be hard to spot what might be wrong. Also, do you get an error message or what exactly is not working?

Comment: In most cases, "errors" are not really errors. As long as the server sends back data to you, it is normal, so you can’t treat it as an error capture, but get the data you want in the normal process.

Comment: Updated the code in the post to show try code - not sure if that's going to help in any way. The response displayed on console.log is simply along the lines of {"message":"Request failed with status code 400"}, but I can see the error code displayed in Chrome > Network > Response